# Regarding the Maximum of Two Stopping Times

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

I am having a difficult time understanding a certain equivalence regarding the maximum of two stopping times. The context is showing, for two stopping times $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$, that $\tau_1 \vee \tau_2$ is a stopping time as well.

I understand that this amounts to showing that the random variable $\tau_1 \vee \tau_2$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable. It is also clear intuitively speaking. The trouble I have is with the intersection in the following
$$\{\tau_1 \vee \tau_2 \le t\} = \{\tau_1 \le t\} \cap \{\tau_2 \le t\}$$

My understanding seems to be wrong, for which I kindly ask for clarification and guidance for, but I would expect (for $\tau_1 \le \tau_2)$ that $\{\tau_1 \le t\} \subseteq \{\tau_2 \le t\}$ to be true -- which is to say, a larger stopping ''accommodates'' more elements in $\Omega$. Under this reasoning, I should expect $$\{\tau_1 \vee \tau_2 \le t\} = \{\tau_1 \le t\} \cup \{\tau_2 \le t\}$$

For reference, I will direct you to [theorems 28 and 38](http://www.randomservices.org/random/prob/Stop.html#prp3.). This is one such example, but several sources seem to verify the intersection, rather than the union, in the equivalence above.

Any intuition and guidance are certainly appreciated!

Comment: The following may help your thinking about this: For each sample point $\omega\in\Omega$ and each $t\ge 0$, you have $\tau_1(\omega)\vee\tau_2(\omega) \le t$ if and only if $\tau_1(\omega)\le t$ *and* $\tau_2(\omega)\le t$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins. That is helpful, thank you. Now what about $\{\tau_1 \le t\} \subseteq \{\tau_2 \le t\}$?

Comment: I think you are assuming $\tau_2 \leq \tau_1$ a.s., but in the question it doesn't say anything about that. It just says "two stopping times".

Comment: @UBM, You're right in that I was thinking about an order, but I was actually thinking that $\tau_1 \le \tau_2$ a.s.

Comment: You'll have $\{\tau_1\le t\}\subset \{\tau_2\le t\}$ for all $t\ge 0$  if and only if $\tau_1(\omega)\ge\tau_2(\omega)$ for all $\omega$.

Comment: @reima: I guessed so but you said $\{\tau_1 \leq t\} \subset \{\tau_2 \leq t \}$ and in order to get that, you have to assume $\tau_2 \leq \tau_1.$

Comment: Thanks @JohnDawkins. It seems then that my understanding of $\{\tau \le t\}$ is incorrect.

Should I be thinking of  $\{ \tau \le t\}$  as "the collection of sample points $\omega \in \Omega$ which allows one to determine if $\tau$ occurred at each $t\ge0$". Then because if we know $\tau_2$ occurred, then $\tau_1$ occurred but not the reverse.

Comment: @JohnDawkins: ah, yes. my 'a.s.' is wrong. It has to be 'for all'.

Comment: $\{\tau\le t\}$ is an abbreviation for $\{\omega\in\Omega: \tau(\omega)\le t\}$.

Comment: Ahah it all just clicked. Thank you both!